# Angular not displaying JSON array data

Tags: angularjs, json

I've spent a few hours on this and I just can't get the array data to display on the page. I'm not getting any errors.

```
     (function() {
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        app.controller('AppController', ['$http', function($http){
            this.files = [];

            $http.get('angular-data.json').success(function(data){
                this.files = data;
            });
        }]);
    })();
```

And inside my angular-data.json file:

```
[{"name": "myfile.doc","ext": "doc","size": "168KB","modified": "5 mins"}]
```

Someone please help :-(

Comment: Please provide your HTML and don't use [**`.success`**](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/)

Comment: The code worked fine when I had the array in the page, so I'm guessing there's some issue with the way I'm calling the JSON data into the array.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Have you got a chance to try my answer. I really think this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `.success` to `.then`

Then convert this

```
this.files = data;
```

to this

```
this.files = data.data;
```

Comment: Regrettably, I get the same result - nothing displayed.

Comment: Can you provide output of this `console.log(data.data)` and you are using `.then` right  ? @DanielWilliams

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.files = data[0];
```

In **angular-data.json** file it have object in array

Comment: That will only ever allow one array item.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `this` in success callback is not getting its context.

Try binding it in `$scope` or if you are using `vm`, just like

for **$scope**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('AppController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
        $scope.files = [];

        $http.get('angular-data.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.files = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

For **vm**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('AppController', ['$http', function($http){
        var vm = this;
        vm.files = [];

        $http.get('angular-data.json').success(function(data){
            vm.files = data;
        });
    }]);
})();
```